# On the relation of $\beta_k=(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j\geq k}a_j^2)^{1/2}$ and $a_n\asymp n^{-s}\log^\alpha(n)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence

I found the following Lemma and I am trying to understand it.

Let $\beta_k=(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j\geq k}a_j^2)^{1/2}$ and $a_n\asymp n^{-s}\log^\alpha(n)$ for some $s,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then,

$$\beta_k\asymp \begin{cases}
a_k, & \text{if } s > \frac{1}{2}, \\
a_k \sqrt{\log(k)}, & \text{if } s = \frac{1}{2} \text{ and } \alpha < -\frac{1}{2}, \\
\infty, & \text{else}.
\end{cases}$$

I know that the series
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{i=2}^n\frac{1}{n^a \log^b(n)}.
\end{equation}
converges for $a>1$ or when $a=1$ and $b>1$.
But I still dont know where the $\sqrt{\log(k)}$ is coming from. Maybe someone has an explanation for this.

Comment: are you sure that the result you claim is correct?

Comment: No, but i found this under lemma 1 on this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02516.
Maybe I am overlooking something

Comment: Aren't you missing a $1/2$ (in the exponent) in the definition of $\beta_k$?

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you

Comment: The way is now the result looks correct and easily follows by the integral comparison and integration by parts

Comment: My idea was if we square the right side and look at the exponent of the $\log$ part in the second case, it should hold that $-2\alpha+1=b>1$, which means $\alpha<0$. Then this is especially true for $\alpha<-1/2$. 
But I am still confused about the additional $log$ part because it should also hold without the $\log$ part or am I wrong?

Comment: when you apply the integral comparison you get that $\beta_k^2 \approx \frac{1}{k}\int_k^{\infty}x^{-2s}\log^{2\alpha}x dx $; if $s=1/2$ integration by parts gives you an extra $\log$ term so you get that $\beta_k^2 \approx \frac{\log ^{2\alpha+1}k}{k}=a_k^2 \log k $ hence the extra log; when $s >1/2$ you just get $C_{s, \alpha}a_k^2$ as the main term so no extra logarithm

Comment: Thank you! 
How did you get the $C_{s,\alpha}$?